# Keyframes não está reconhecendo o comando

Tags: html5, css3, notepad++

Olas! 
Estou tendo problemas para usar essa rule pois ele nao esta reconhecendo a primeira linha, logo, nao executa a animaçao. 
Nao sei mais o q fazer, pq mesmo que eu apague a linha, a de baixo passa a nao ser reconhecida mais. 
O que eu percebi é q quando está com um colchete "{" aberto e coloco a primeira porcentagem e abro outro colchete "{" pra definir o efeito, fecho o colchete "}" e passo pro segundo percentual para outro efeito, essa primeira linha nao fica reconhecida como comando, somente a segunda.
Ou seja, ele nao esta aceitando dois colchetes aberto na mesma rule. {{ }}

Por favor, se alguem já passou por isso, ficaria muito agradecido com a ajuda.
Agradeço desde já.

PS.: A foto eu mantive para poderem ver a questao da aceitaçao do codigo pela cor caracteristicas dos editores, que no caso nao está azul como deveria.

HTML CODE

    Slide Show

```
<style>*{padding: 0; margin:0;}</style>
```

Slider Teste

```
<section class="galeria">
    <img class="foto" src="imagem 1.jpg" />
    <img class="foto" src="imagem 2.jpg" />
    <img class="foto" src="imagem 3.jpg" />
</section>
```

```
CSS CODE  
section.galeria {  
margin: 200px auto;  
width: 480px;  
position: relative;  
overflow: hidden;  
}  
section.foto {  
position: absolute;  
opacity: 0;  
animation-name: animacao;  
}  
@keyframes animacao {  
25% {  
    opacity: 1;  
    transform: scale(1.1,1.1);  
}  
50% {  
    opacity: 0;  
}  
}
```

==========================================================

[image: Nao reconhece a primeira linha da rule]
[image: Reconhece fechando o colchetes de forma errada]

Comment: seguinte como você está chamando a função quais parametros está sendo passando para que `animacao` seja executada? outra coisa esses trechos de código você pode inseri-los diretamente na pergunta sem a necessidade de inserir imagens.

Comment: Isso não é colchete, é chave :p

Comment: >> DvD>> pior, errei feio, valew pelo aviso.

>>WMomesso>> Coloquei na pergunta editada, aqui ficou fora de identaçao.:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na chamada da `keyframe` tem que ser determinado o tempo de execução a estrutura deve demorar para ser concluindo e o período que pode ser até infinito, onde a mesma fica em looping, outra coisa a ser observada é se a versão do navegador suporta as rules.

Exemplo:
algumas versões de navegadores precisam de um `prefixo` para funcionarem, pois não possuem nativamente a funcionalidade.

> Alguns prefixos:

- `-webkit-` para algumas versões do chrome, opera e safari.
- `-moz-` para firefox.

Para entender como os sufixos funcionam e como implementa-los acesse o [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp)

Abaixo tem uma amostra do código funcionando.

```css
.div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  animation: animacao 5s infinite;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@keyframes animacao {
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: 1.1, 1.1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
    border-radius:45px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="div"></div>
```

Comment: O efeito de sumir funcionou, mas fica com uma imagem embaixo da outra ao mesmo tempo, nao fica alternando entre elas.

Comment: Tiago não vejo neste código detalhes para que as imagens de alternem, te aconselho e dar como concluída esta questão e abrir uma nova sobre o slide e acrescente o código js

Comment: Sim, acabei de perceber que perdi o codigo completo. Vou reescreve-lo.
Muito obrigado.